# Problemas com "libpq.so.5": wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 em C

Tags: c, postgresql, ubuntu, lib

Estou tentando rodar um arquivo compilado em c sendo que recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

"error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64"

Fiz uma busca e identifiquei que esse tipo de erro é devido as bibliotecas x64 e x86, mas não encontrei em canto algum como solucionar esse problema.

Já fiz a instalação dos pacotes do postgresql e libpq5 mas não adiantou.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionei o problema com a instalação da libpq5:i386

```
sudo apt-get install libpq5:i386
```

Deixo minha contribuição para galera.